# changing language on application page

Tags: 2010, javascript, application-pages, language

I am using following code to change the language of HTML form on application page:

```
 <asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.Core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.Debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.Runtime.Debug.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ChangeLanguage(value) {
    var today = new Date();
    var oneYear = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var url = window.location.href;
    document.cookie = "lcid=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + oneYear.toGMTString();
    window.location.href = url;
}

</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<form>
// My Html form is here.. with 3 input type text and one input type submit button

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ChangeLanguage(1053);">swedish</a>
<a href="javascript:ChangeLanguage(1033)">english</a>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

When i click on any of the hyperlinks above, nothing happened. I could not understand, what is wrong? I am using two types of links, but neither works

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I don't think you need to take `<form>` tag in application page! Also put `alert('function called');` in your JavaScript function to see if it is ever called...

Comment: As i check by putting alert('function called'); in ChangeLanguage() JavaScript function, but it never called.. Also i check from outside of <form> tag, but did not work.

Comment: Instead of placing `<script>` tag in "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead", place it inside "Main" without `<form>`

Comment: Still did not work.....??

Comment: Make sure the script tag is included in the page, View source for the page to make sure! Also change function name from ChangeLanguage to customChangeLanguage

Comment: it is not necessary but it will be better to use SP.js and SP.Runtime.js. The debug scripts are loaded if you set it in web config.

Comment: I have added SP.js and SP.Runtime.js. But still ChangeLanguage() JavaScript method did not called. I am still confused, is that correct Place to put JavaScript function.